# How does one obfuscate code in C?

Tags: c, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate code just for fun. I'm looking at code from the international obfuscated c contest: http://www.ioccc.org/ And I seriously just have no idea how to even start reverse engineering some of this code to make anything of sense.

What are some common obfuscation techniques and how do you make sense of obfuscated code?

Comment: Are you asking how to obfuscate code (the question in your title), or how to understand obfuscated code (the body of your question)?

Comment: The first step in making sense of obfuscated code is adding whitespace. Then you should probably learn about [digraphs and trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs). Then you just need to work through the code. As for how to obfuscate, everyone probably has their own techniques.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Both.. I asked "what common obfuscation techniques are" as well as understanding obfuscated code. I figured that if I can understand how to de-obfuscate code then that will help me understand how to obfuscate it.

Comment: @Dukeling Very interesting. Thanks for the link - I had never heard of such a thing before

Comment: the best way (and the sorts of things which win those contests) is to think of some clever new way to obfuscate your code. Playing with the preprocessor (`#define` and trigraphs) is pretty old-hat. If you want quality obfuscation, it should still be weird after preprocessing. Things like building your own stack, manipulating floats as bytes, and exploiting strange edge-cases of the standard are good contenders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot of different techniques to obfuscate code, here is a small, very incomplete list:

1. Identifier mangling. Either you will find people using names like a, b, c exclusively, or you find identifiers that have absolutely nothing to do with the actual purpose of the variable/function. Deobfuscation would be to assign sensible names.
2. Heavy use of the conditional evaluation operator `? :`, replacing all occurences of `if() else`. In most cases that's a lot harder to read, deobfuscation would reinsert `if()`.
3. Heavy use of the comma operator instead of `;`. In combination with 2. and 4., this basically allows the entire program to be one single statement in `main()`.
4. Recursive calls of `main()`. You can fold *any* function into main by having an argument that main can use to decide what to do. Combine this with replacing loops by recursion, and you end up with the entire program being the main function.
5. You can go the exact opposite direction to 3. and 4., and hack everything into pieces by creating an insane amount of functions that all do virtually nothing.
6. You can obfuscate the storage of an array by storing the values on the stack. Should you need to walk the data twice, there's always the `fork()` call handy to make a convenient copy of your stack.

As I said, this is a very incomplete list, but generally, obfuscation is usually the heavy, systematic abuse of any valid programming technique. If the IOCCC were allowing C++ entries, I would bet on a *lot* of template code entering, making heavy use of throwing exceptions as an if replacement, hiding structure behind polymorphism, etc.